# Make pd.to_datetime() quicker

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a question regarding pandas :

I have large date of 3 million rows, with a column 'Time' in the format : '%m/%d/%Y %H%M' (so, 02/28/2021 0:00 for instance).
When I try running pd.to_datetime() on this, specifying the format, it takes about 7 seconds.
Way too long.

I tried to do the following : took all unique values for dates (drop_duplicates(), about 800 unique values), then from that recreate a dataframe of approx 3 million rows using 'repeat'. When I did :

```
no_duplicates = initial_df['Time'].drop_duplicates()
no_duplicates = no_duplicates.repeat(4000) #approx. 3 million rows
df = pd.DataFrame({'Timestamp' : no_duplicates}) 
pd.to_datetime(df.Timestamp, format = '%m/%d/%Y %H%M')
```

It took only 254 ms..

I first thought it was because 'repeat' was doing something in place (so changing 1 would change all similar rows), but that is not the case (to check, I exported the dataframe no_duplicates to csv and reimported it, still run in 254 ms.).
To my surprise, when running :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Timestamp' : no_duplicates.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)}) #reshuffling the rows
pd.to_datetime(df.Timestamp, format = '%m/%d/%Y %H%M')
```

This, again, took 7 seconds.

So, the order of rows seems to have an impact. Why is that? And how can I group all rows that have same dates in my initial dataframe and make them consecutive (or if you have any other way to speed it up, I'd gladly take it.).
Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

*any other way to speed it up*

[pandas.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) has argument `cache` which

*If True, use a cache of unique, converted dates to apply the datetime conversion. May produce significant speed-up when parsing duplicate date strings, especially ones with timezone offsets. The cache is only used when there are at least 50 values. The presence of out-of-bounds values will render the cache unusable and may slow down parsing.
Changed in version 0.25.0: - changed default value from False to True.*

Please check which version you are using (`import pandas;print(pandas.__version__)`) and if it is lower than `0.25.0` try feeding `cache=True`

Answer (score 0):

I tried different solutions and I confirm your findings.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

first_date = '2020-01-01'
date_range_sample = pd.date_range(
    start=pd.to_datetime(first_date),
    end=pd.to_datetime(first_date) + pd.Timedelta(hours=800-1),
    freq='H'
)

date_range = np.repeat(date_range_sample, 4000)
date_range_str = date_range.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H%M')
date_range_str_shuffled = date_range_str.copy(deep=True)

np.random.seed(0)
np.random.shuffle(date_range_str_shuffled.to_numpy())

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': date_range_str,
    'date_shuffled': date_range_str_shuffled,
})
```

Using `df.date` is very fast

```
%timeit pd.to_datetime(df.date, format='%m/%d/%Y %H%M')
312 ms ± 2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Using the shuffled date column is much slower

```
%timeit pd.to_datetime(df.date_shuffled, format='%m/%d/%Y %H%M')
6.46 s ± 19.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

But if we sort the DataFrame by the shuffled datetime, we get back to faster behavior

```
df.sort_values(by='date_shuffled', inplace=True)
%timeit pd.to_datetime(df.date_shuffled, format='%m/%d/%Y %H%M')
441 ms ± 1.09 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

But... it'd take almost 4 secs to sort the shuffled dates

```
%timeit pd.to_datetime(
    df.sort_values(by='date_shuffled').date_shuffled, 
    format='%m/%d/%Y %H%M'
    )
4.86 s ± 45.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Hi Max, thank you very much for this, helps recreate it for everyone.
Yes, I did try sorting afterwards but as you mentioned, still very long.. Not sure why pandas is doing this, hopefully somebody will be able to answer.
Best